# PL/SQL if statement ignored in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to throw an exception in a before insert or update trigger when one of the fields is empty or null using the following code:

```
if :new.reactietekst = null or :new.reactietekst = '' then 
  raise invalid_text; 
end if;
```

However when I try to do an insert with an empty or null value for the reactietekst field the code seems to be ignored. The other exceptions in my trigger work fine.

Test inserts:

```
insert into Reactie values (5,'Jan Janssen',to_date('21-12-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'89.98.10.12',null, 'NIEUW', 1); 
insert into Reactie values (5,'Jan Janssen',to_date('21-12-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'89.98.10.12','', 'NIEUW', 1);
```

Full trigger code:

```
create or replace trigger check_reactie
before update or insert
on REACTIE
for each row
declare
  invalid_capitals EXCEPTION;
  invalid_ip exception;
  invalid_text exception;
begin
  if isdutchip(:new.ipadres) = false then 
    raise invalid_ip;
  end if;
  if :new.reactietekst = null or :new.reactietekst = '' then 
    raise invalid_text; 
  end if;
  if :new.naam != initcap(:new.naam) then
    raise invalid_capitals;
  end if;
  if inserting then
    :new.status := 'NIEUW';
  end if;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN invalid_capitals THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Alle woorden in de naam moeten met hoofdletter beginnen!');
  WHEN invalid_ip THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reacties mogen alleen vanaf een nederlands ip adress worden geplaats!');
  WHEN invalid_text THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reactie moet tekst bevatten!');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle, `NULL` and empty string are the same.  In SQL, you cannot compare to `NULL` using `=`.  Just do:

```
if :new.reactietekst is null then 
  raise invalid_text; 
end if;
```